# Exists there a language in which the patient of transitive verbs and the single argument of intransitive verbs are treated alike?

Tags: morphosyntax

I am somewhat familiar with (not at all learned of)the morphosyntactic criteria by which many languages are classified--such as the system by which the grammatical abstractions of agent, argument, and patient are  treated-- and descried of the criteria potency unto a numerosity of classes yborn of this method of linguistic taxonomy. Being a trinary collection, the abstractions before listed may be partitioned such that unto every set (of a given partition) is assigned a speciality of morphosyntactic treatment; the set of all partitions logically distinguishable would bear  a cardinality of five and include sorts of languages neither ergative-abslutive nor nominative-accusative.

Namely I query pose as to the existence of a language per which the patient of transitive verbs is treated as is the agent of transitive verbs. Specifically I muse at yet on such a language which as well treats the single argument of intransitive verbs differently than the other two said abstractions.

I know of languages which may not so neatly fall into any of the classes for which the described partitions account (such as split ergative and active-stative languages) and if response to my inquiry requires disqualification of some premise I've supposed of linguistic taxonomy, I grant the nicety of direct answer may be hence precluded as the same may only transpire upon congruence between him positing and the interlocutor as to the presumed veridical obtentions as for the topic of their discourse.

I greatly appreciate any and all consideration given to this question.

Comment: Jarrod, I'm terribly curious what your native language is.

Comment: +1 just for using "yborn"

Comment: If I follow you correctly, this is just an ergative-absolutive language, of which there are many examples. You write, "the patient of transitive verbs and the single argument of intransitive verbs" -- or the Object of a transitive clause is aligned with the Subject of an intransitive clause, correct? In such languages, the Agent of the transitive clause is in the Ergative case.

Comment: Opprobrium befits my assay at querenthood as it seems I've failed in making the principal distinction by which this positing may have enjoyed firmity as anything more workable than mere case of inane misunderstanding of that the question concerned. Yes, the alignment about which I asked would be one of an ergative-absolutive language. I meant to ask of a language which treated the agent of transitive verbs as it does the patient of such verbs, letting the single argument of intransitive verbs to their own morphosyntactic speciality. Exists there such a language of the morphosyntaxes given?

Comment: Please edit your question to reflect your revised query.

Comment: By the way, an example is the [Rushani language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rushani_language) (though only in the past tense).

Comment: Quite interesting is this dialect, as well as the theory that such evolved from a split-ergative language from leveling of the case forms of the object. Is this the only known occasion of such a morphosyntax, and if not do such languages typically exist but for a brevity before mutating in a sort of natural absquatulation from linguistic peculiarity?

Comment: But this answer was rather satisfying to my curiosities; I'd fain betake myself to such as suffices postulates as parcel of my query. Thank you-

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morphosyntactic_alignment

Comment: For those of you playing along at home, the OP's post is an example of [Wardour Street English](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Wardour+Street).

Comment: Jarrod, please write more perspicuously.